# Should I be using generics to simplify my configuration provider class?

Tags: c#, generics

I am attempting to write a configuration manager that can supply configuration settings from different providers (e.g. settings files, environment variables, databases etc).

I have envisioned that the settings will be either strings, ints or doubles and will be identified by a name

Settings are provided via classes implementing this:

```
public interface IConfigurationManagerProvider
{
    T GetSetting<T>(string name);
    IEnumerable<ConfigurationSetting> GetKnownSettings();
}
```

As a start I am trying to write a provider to return environment variables

```
public class EnvironmentVariableProvider : IConfigurationManagerProvider
{
    public T GetSetting<T>(string name) 
    {
        string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name);
        return value as T;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ConfigurationSetting> GetKnownSettings()
    {
        return new List<ConfigurationSetting>
        {
            new ConfigurationSetting("MY_TRACKING", typeof (String)),
        };
    }
}
```

however this won't compile as it can't cast to T.
If I put a class constraint in then this limits me to strings

```
public T GetSetting<T>(string name) where T : class
{
    string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name);
    return value as T;
}
```

Really this provider can only supply strings (other providers will be different) however I want the code to access the configuration settings to be as clean as possible using something like:

```
public interface IConfigurationManagerConsumer
{
    T GetConfiguration<T>(string name, T systemDefault);
}
```

and used like this:

```
string tracking = ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration("MY_TRACKING", "Unknown");
```

or this:

```
int maxUserCount = ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration("MAX_USER_COUNT", 10);
```

or this:

```
double pi = ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration("PI", 3.14159);
```

Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
```

Comment: Cheers. I'll take that as an implied "Yes that is the right approach" :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a vaguely similar variable provider interface, in which I didn't use generics.  I started out with generics, and found that it didn't make the code any more readable or performant, particularly since the types were few and known from the start.  After all, you're not getting anything dynamic, it is inferring the type from the default value you give.  I also wanted my variable provider to be usable without providing a default value, and didn't want to use a different syntax for that.

So mine consists of two levels.  One is public interface provider that I use in code, which can be used like in these examples:

```
IVariableProvider var;

// providing default value
double pi = var.Double["pi", 3.14159];

// no default value, also bool is just an int, converted by the IVariableProvider.
bool answer = var.Bool["answer"];
int number = var.Int["number"];


if(var.Str.ContainsKey("text"))
{
    string text = var.Str["text"];
    ...
}
```

I could add public interfaces for var.Float, var.Long, etc if desired.

Underneath, the `IVariableProvider` can be given different "sources" to get variables from.  The sources only expose string and integer.  It can use other `IVariableProvider`s as sources as well.  When I call `var.Double["pi"]`, it checks if any of the sources can provide a string variable for the key "pi" and then `double.Parse()` and return it.

Ultimately, you can do it either way.  If you use generics like that and then want to use it without default values, you'll have to use different syntax in order to specify the type.

Comment: Excellent, thanks that is giving me something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661067/22817151) of [Muhammad Hasan Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36464/muhammad-hasan-khan).

I wrote a [nuget library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kurnakov.GenericEnvironment).

Installation:

```
dotnet add package Kurnakov.GenericEnvironment
```

Code example:

```
using GenericEnv;

double pi = GenericEnvironment.GetEnvironmentVariable<double>("PI");
```

In your case, when you need a default value, you can use this:

```
using GenericEnv;

double pi = GenericEnvironment.TryGetEnvironmentVariable("PI", out pi) ? pi : 3.14159;
string myTracking = GenericEnvironment.TryGetEnvironmentVariable("MY_TRACKING", out myTracking) ? myTracking : "Unknown";
int maxUserCount = GenericEnvironment.TryGetEnvironmentVariable("MAX_USER_COUNT", out maxUserCount) ? maxUserCount : 10;
```

This code can be easily to test, because we can write mocks:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PI", "3.14159");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MY_TRACKING", "Mock");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MAX_USER_COUNT", "100");
```

More details you can find [here](https://github.com/kurnakovv/GenericEnvironment)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, and thanks for responding!
Please edit your response to add the relevant content from your referenced link from which you derived your answer.
External links can and do go obsolete.  Adding the content to your answer will make it more relevant in the future.
Thanks!

Comment: @Mmm I'm not sure how I can add relevant content from link's. Can you please add more details? IMHO, my answer is full, and anyone can use my solution without external link's. I added external link's only for more details.

Comment: On further review, I believe you are correct.  Thanks, and sorry for any confusion.